# Implement sliding window on file lines in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, moving-average, sliding-window, file-traversal

I'm trying to implement a sliding/moving window approach on lines of a csv file using Python. Each line can have a column with a binary value `yes` or `no`. Basically, I want to rare `yes` noises. That means if say we have **3** `yes` lines **in a window of 5** (max of 5), keep them. But if there is 1 or 2, let's change them to `no`. How can I do that?

For instance, the following `yes` should both become `no`.

```
...
1,a1,b1,no,0.75
2,a2,b2,no,0.45
3,a3,b3,yes,0.98
4,a4,b4,yes,0.22
5,a5,b5,no,0.46
6,a6,b6,no,0.20
...
```

But in the followings, we keep as is (there can be a window of 5 where 3 of them are `yes`):

```
...
1,a1,b1,no,0.75
2,a2,b2,no,0.45
3,a3,b3,yes,0.98
4,a4,b4,yes,0.22
5,a5,b5,no,0.46
6,a6,b6,yes,0.20
...
```

I attempted writing something, having a window of 5, but got stuck (it is not complete):

```
        window_size = 5 
        filename='C:\\Users\\username\\v3\\And-'+v3file.split("\\")[5]
        with open(filename) as fin:
            with open('C:\\Users\\username\\v4\\And2-'+v3file.split("\\")[5],'w') as finalout:
                line= fin.readline()
                index = 0
                sequence= []
                accs=[]
                while line:
                    print(line)
                    for i in range(window_size):
                        line = fin.readline()
                        sequence.append(line)
                    index = index + 1
                    fin.seek(index)
```

Comment: Are you trying to solve, keeping the most recent three rows an a variable/window?

Comment: @wwii Actually let's say max out of a window of 5 (3 yes not necessarily need to be all in sequence). Updated the question a bit.

Comment: Is the file very large? Is it important to read one line of the file at a time? If you read the entire file into memory, your problem becomes easier and code will become cleaner, and you don't have to do things like `fin.seek`

Comment: Can you provide a more complete sample, and what the subsequent output should look like?

Comment: @vasia file can be up to 10MB. But if you think it fits memory, then fine.

Comment: @PMende added another example. I think it is clear enough now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `collections.deque` with the `maxlen` argument set to the desired window size to implement a sliding window that keeps track of the yes/no flags of the most recent 5 rows. Keep a count of yeses instead of calculating the sum of yeses in the sliding window in every iteration to be more efficient. When you have a full-size sliding window and the count of yeses is greater than 2, add the line indices of these yeses to a set where the yeses should be kept as-is. And the in the second pass after resetting the file pointer of the input, alter the yeses to noes if the line indices are not in the set:

```
from collections import deque

window_size = 5
with open(filename) as fin, open(output_filename, 'w') as finalout:
    yeses = 0
    window = deque(maxlen=5)
    preserved = set()
    for index, line in enumerate(fin):
        window.append('yes' in line)
        if window[-1]:
            yeses += 1
        if len(window) == window_size:
            if yeses > 2:
                preserved.update(i for i, f in enumerate(window, index - window_size + 1) if f)
            if window[0]:
                yeses -= 1
    fin.seek(0)
    for index, line in enumerate(fin):
        if index not in preserved:
            line = line.replace('yes', 'no')
        finalout.write(line)
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/StripedCleanCopyrightinfringement

Comment: Thanks. Any chance **not** to use `csv`? Let's just generalize to a text file where `yes` exists in a line. I didn't add csv in my title to make it general.

Comment: Edited accordingly then.

Comment: Trying now...Hopefully no issues.

Comment: @TinaJ Since it's actually a CSV, I don't think telling people to generalize is going to help give you the correct solution. It's pretty trivial to read the CSV correctly and doesn't add any complexity (if anything, it reduces complexity).

Comment: @ggorlen I see. Thanks. @blhsing Now if I want to get max of 10 rows (window size of 10) what numbers should I exactly change? I see many numbers inside. Can you make `window_size=5` a variable and adapt other numbers accordingly?

Comment: Edited accordingly then.

Comment: Great, it works. And `yeses > 2` was supposed to be the max count of the whole window, but already know how to edit that. So Thanks!

Comment: please take a look at my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59402149

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 5-liner solution based on building successive list comprehensions:

```
lines = [
'1,a1,b1,no,0.75',
'2,a2,b2,yes,0.45',
'3,a3,b3,yes,0.98',
'4,a4,b4,yes,0.22',
'5,a5,b5,no,0.46',
'6,a6,b6,no,0.98',
'7,a7,b7,yes,0.22',
'8,a8,b8,no,0.46',
'9,a9,b9,no,0.20']

n = len(lines)

# flag all lines containing 'yes' (add 2 empty lines at boundaries to avoid pbs)
flags = [line.count('yes') for line in ['', '']+lines+['', '']]
# count number of flags in sliding window [p-2,p+2]
counts = [sum(flags[p-2:p+3]) for p in range(2,n+2)]
# tag lines that need to be changed
tags = [flag > 0 and count < 3 for (flag,count) in zip(flags[2:],counts)]
# change tagged lines
for n in range(n):
  if tags[n]: lines[n] = lines[n].replace('yes','no')

print(lines)
```

Result:

```
['1,a1,b1,no,0.75',
 '2,a2,b2,yes,0.45',
 '3,a3,b3,yes,0.98',
 '4,a4,b4,yes,0.22',
 '5,a5,b5,no,0.46',
 '6,a6,b6,no,0.98',
 '7,a7,b7,no,0.22',
 '8,a8,b8,no,0.46',
 '9,a9,b9,no,0.20']
```

EDIT : As you read your data from a standard text file, all you have to do is:

```
with file(filename,'r') as f:
  lines = f.read().strip().split('\n')
```

(strip to remove potential blank lines at top or bottom on file, split(\n) to turn file content into a list of lines) then use the code above...

Comment: Thanks. Can you complete your code with reading from and writing to a file?

Comment: Nice chat indeed. I remove my comments also. Regards