# How to merge continuous lines of a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, csv, file-processing

I have a csv file that carries outputs of some processes over video frames. In the file, each line is either `fire` or `none`. Each line has `startTime` and `endTime`. Now I need to cluster and print only one instance out of **continuous fires** with their **start** and **end** time. The point is that a few `none` in the middle can also be tolerated if their time is within **1** second. So to be clear, the whole point is to cluster detections of closer frames together...somehow smooth out the results. Instead of multiple `31-32, 32-33, ...`, have a single line with `31-35` seconds.

How to do that?

For instance, the whole following continuous items are considered a single one since the `none` gaps is within 1s. So we would have something like `1,file1,name1,30.6,32.2,fire,0.83` with that score being the mean of all fire lines.

```
frame_num,uniqueId,title,startTime,endTime,startTime_fmt,object,score
...
10,file1,name1,30.6,30.64,0:00:30,fire,0.914617
11,file1,name1,30.72,30.76,0:00:30,none,0.68788
12,file1,name1,30.84,30.88,0:00:30,fire,0.993345
13,file1,name1,30.96,31,0:00:30,fire,0.991015
14,file1,name1,31.08,31.12,0:00:31,fire,0.983197
15,file1,name1,31.2,31.24,0:00:31,fire,0.979572
16,file1,name1,31.32,31.36,0:00:31,fire,0.985898
17,file1,name1,31.44,31.48,0:00:31,none,0.961606
18,file1,name1,31.56,31.6,0:00:31,none,0.685139
19,file1,name1,31.68,31.72,0:00:31,none,0.458374
20,file1,name1,31.8,31.84,0:00:31,none,0.413711
21,file1,name1,31.92,31.96,0:00:31,none,0.496828
22,file1,name1,32.04,32.08,0:00:32,fire,0.412836
23,file1,name1,32.16,32.2,0:00:32,fire,0.383344
```

This is my attempts so far:

```
with open(filename) as fin:
    lastWasFire=False
    for line in fin:
        if "fire" in line:
             if lastWasFire==False and line !="" and line.split(",")[5] != lastline.split(",")[5]:
                  fout.write(line)
             else:
                lastWasFire=False
             lastline=line
```

Comment: can you make the description more clear? what you have, which lines from the csv you are going to sum or clusterize and why, how you calculate the resulting score & times & etc. now it is not clear enough

Comment: @sciroccorics I already said the score is mean of fires.

Comment: @AlexandrShurigin whole point is detections of closer frames be clustered together...somehow smooth out the results.

Comment: @blhsing if you are interested...

Comment: Heh that's just a sample!!

Comment: yeah whatever it is.

Comment: never thought u would calculate the real mean!

Comment: ok i will try in the morning...tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you don't want to use external libraries for data processing like `numpy` or `pandas`. The following code should be quite similar to your attempt:

```py
threshold = 1.0

# We will chain a "none" object at the end which triggers the threshold to make sure no "fire" objects are left unprinted
from itertools import chain
trigger = (",,,0,{},,none,".format(threshold + 1),)

# Keys for columns of input data
keys = (
    "frame_num",
    "uniqueId",
    "title",
    "startTime",
    "endTime",
    "startTime_fmt",
    "object",
    "score",
)

# Store last "fire" or "none" objects
last = {
    "fire": [],
    "none": [],
}

with open(filename) as f:
    # Skip first line of input file
    next(f)
    for line in chain(f, trigger):
        line = dict(zip(keys, line.split(",")))
        last[line["object"]].append(line)
        # Check threshold for "none" objects if there are previous unprinted "fire" objects
        if line["object"] == "none" and last["fire"]:
            if float(last["none"][-1]["endTime"]) - float(last["none"][0]["startTime"]) > threshold:
                print("{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}".format(
                    last["fire"][0]["frame_num"],
                    last["fire"][0]["uniqueId"],
                    last["fire"][0]["title"],
                    last["fire"][0]["startTime"],
                    last["fire"][-1]["endTime"],
                    last["fire"][0]["startTime_fmt"],
                    last["fire"][0]["object"],
                    sum([float(x["score"]) for x in last["fire"]]) / len(last["fire"]),
                ))
                last["fire"] = []
        # Previous "none" objects don't matter anymore as soon as a "fire" object is being encountered
        if line["object"] == "fire":
            last["none"] = []
```

The input file is being processed line by line and `"fire"` objects are being accumulated in `last["fire"]`. They will be merged and printed if either

- the `"none"` objects in `last["none"]` reach the threshold defined in `threshold`
- or when the end of the input file is reached due to the manually chained `trigger` object, which is a `"none"` object of length `threshold + 1`, therefore triggering the threshold and subsequent merge and print.

You could replace `print` with a call to write into an output file, of course.

Comment: I was trying to use it now...But get `KeyError: 'object'` on `last[line["object"]].append(line)`

Comment: For instance, I get this two lines separately: `13101,name1,name2,524.04,524.32,0:08:44,Fire,0.9999046666666667
13143,name1,name2,525.72,527.32,0:08:45,Fire,0.9960832142857142`. If the times are within 1s (44 and 45), they need to be merged as a single line, with startTime and endTime showing the interval. So should be `13101,name1,name2,524.04,527.32,0:08:44,Fire,0.9999046666666667`

Comment: Umm u are right (I was looking at that 8:45 thing). so it was <1s, the would have been merged?! Maybe u should compare the int() of them.

Comment: Yes. It works actually. I set it for 2 with `int()` modifications. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is close to what you are looking for and may be an acceptable alternative.

If your sample rate is quite stable (looks to be about 0.12s or 50 Hz) then you can find the equivalent number of samples you can tolerate to be `'none'`.  Let's say that's 8.

This code will read in the data and fill the 'none' values with up to 8 of the last valid value.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def groups_of_true_values(x):
    """Returns array of integers where each True value in x
    is replaced by the count of the group of consecutive
    True values that it was found in.
    """
    return (np.diff(np.concatenate(([0], np.array(x, dtype=int)))) == 1).cumsum()*x 

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0)
# Forward-fill the 'none' values to a limit
df['filled'] = df['object'].replace('none', None).fillna(method='ffill', limit=8)

# Find the groups of consecutive fire values
df['group'] = groups_of_true_values(df['filled'] == 'fire')

# Produce sum of scores by group
group_scores = df[['group', 'score']].groupby('group').sum()  
print(group_scores)

# Find firing start and stop times
df['start'] = ((df['filled'] == 'fire') & (df['filled'].shift(1) == 'none'))
df['stop'] = ((df['filled'] == 'none') & (df['filled'].shift(1) == 'fire'))
start_times = df.loc[df['start'], 'startTime'].to_list()  
stop_times = df.loc[df['stop'], 'startTime'].to_list()
print(start_times, stop_times)
```

Output:

```
           score
group           
1      10.347362
[] []
```

Hopefully, the output would be more interesting if there were longer sequences of no firing...

Answer (score 0):

My approach, using `pandas` and `groupby`:

1. Combine continuous lines of the same object (`fire` or `none`) into a spell
2. Drop none-fire spells with duration less than 1 second
3. Combine continuous series of spells of the same object (`fire` or `none`) into a superspell, and calculate the corresponding score

I assume the data is sorted by time (otherwise we need to add a sort after reading the data). The trick to combining continuous lines of the same object into spells/superspells is: first, identify where the new spell/superspell starts (i.e. when the object type changes), and second, assign a unique id to each spell (= the number of new spell before it)

```
import pandas as pd

# preparing the test data
data = '''frame_num,uniqueId,title,startTime,endTime,startTime_fmt,object,score
10,file1,name1,30.6,30.64,0:00:30,fire,0.914617
11,file1,name1,30.72,30.76,0:00:30,none,0.68788
12,file1,name1,30.84,30.88,0:00:30,fire,0.993345
13,file1,name1,30.96,31,0:00:30,fire,0.991015
14,file1,name1,31.08,31.12,0:00:31,fire,0.983197
15,file1,name1,31.2,31.24,0:00:31,fire,0.979572
16,file1,name1,31.32,31.36,0:00:31,fire,0.985898
17,file1,name1,31.44,31.48,0:00:31,none,0.961606
18,file1,name1,31.56,31.6,0:00:31,none,0.685139
19,file1,name1,31.68,31.72,0:00:31,none,0.458374
20,file1,name1,31.8,31.84,0:00:31,none,0.413711
21,file1,name1,31.92,31.96,0:00:31,none,0.496828
22,file1,name1,32.04,32.08,0:00:32,fire,0.412836
23,file1,name1,32.16,32.2,0:00:32,fire,0.383344'''

with open("a.txt", 'w') as f:
    print(data, file=f)
df1 = pd.read_csv("a.txt")



# mark new spell (the start of a series of continuous lines of the same object)
# new spell if the current object is different from the previous object
df1['newspell'] = df1.object != df1.object.shift(1)

# give each spell a unique spell number (equal to the total number of new spell before it)
df1['spellnum'] = df1.newspell.cumsum()

# group lines from the same spell together
spells = df1.groupby(by=["uniqueId", "title", "spellnum", "object"]).agg(
        first_frame = ('frame_num', 'min'),
        last_frame = ('frame_num', 'max'),
        startTime = ('startTime', 'min'),
        endTime = ('endTime', 'max'),
        totalScore = ('score', 'sum'),
        cnt = ('score', 'count')).reset_index()

# remove none-fire spells with duration less than 1
spells = spells[(spells.object == 'fire') | (spells.endTime > spells.startTime + 1)]


# Now group conitnous fire spells into superspells
# mark new superspell
spells['newsuperspell'] = spells.object != spells.object.shift(1)

# give each superspell a unique number
spells['superspellnum'] = spells.newsuperspell.cumsum()

superspells = spells.groupby(by=["uniqueId", "title", "superspellnum", "object"]).agg(
        first_frame = ('first_frame', 'min'),
        last_frame = ('last_frame', 'max'),
        startTime = ('startTime', 'min'),
        endTime = ('endTime', 'max'),
        totalScore = ('totalScore', 'sum'),
        cnt = ('cnt', 'sum')).reset_index()

superspells['score'] = superspells.totalScore/superspells.cnt
superspells.drop(columns=['totalScore', 'cnt'], inplace=True)

print(superspells.to_csv(index=False))

# output
#uniqueId,title,superspellnum,object,first_frame,last_frame,startTime,endTime,score
#file1,name1,1,fire,10,23,30.6,32.2,0.8304779999999999
```